# Why are less dense materials better thermal conductors?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, material-science, density, thermal-conductivity

As far as I understand a material is a better thermal conductor if its thermal diffusivity is higher. The thermal diffusivity is inversely proportional to density, thus denser materials have higher thermal diffusivity all else being equal. Intuitively I would have expected the opposite to be true! Atoms close together interact more often with each other, transporting thermal energy more easily. In my mind that would explain why gases (and 'zero density' vacuum) are good insulators.

Why exactly low density improve thermal diffusivity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The premise isn't really correct as stated.

It's materials with a higher [thermal conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conductivity) that are better thermal conductors; that is, a given temperature gradient produces a higher conductive heat flux (or a given conductive heat flux can be obtained with a smaller temperature gradient), in accordance with [Fourier's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction#Fourier%27s_law).

Since thermal conductivity is distinct from thermal diffusivity, we avoid the apparent density-related contradictions involving gases and insulators that are mentioned in the question.

So what are materials with a higher [thermal diffusivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_diffusivity) better at? Well, they transfer heat faster over a given length; the characteristic time for thermal diffusion is $\frac{L^2}{D}$, where $L$ is the length of interest and $D$ is the thermal diffusivity. If we start out with an unmaintained temperature gradient in a material, for example,  then we can expect a large portion of it to even out within the characteristic diffusion time and for it to be nearly completely flattened after a few multiples of that time.

If only the density is changed, as you note, the thermal diffusivity changes inversely. One interpretation of this is that as thermal information propagates, a smaller (greater) amount of mass per given volume heats up/cools down more (less) easily in the process of propagating the temperature change onward, as mediated by the [heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity); with less (more) signal attenuation, large changes propagate faster (slower), and so the characteristic time is shorter (longer).

Answer (score 2):

Thermal diffusivity $\alpha$ is

$$\alpha = \frac k {\rho c_p}$$

as we know.  $k$ is the thermal conductivity, which is how much energy will flow through a given amount of the material for a given temperature difference.

The product $\rho c_p$ is the **volumetric heat capacity** of the material:

$$[\rm{ kg/m^3] \cdot [J/(kg \cdot K)]    }  = [J/(m^3 \cdot K)]  $$

It represents the amount of heat an object can hold in a given unit of volume.

So diffusivity is the ratio of how fast heat can move to how much heat can be absorbed.  A material with high $\rho c_p$ can absorb a lot of heat, so each new portion that gets heated will take a long time to reach a high temperature, meaning the heat is slower to spread. A material with low $\rho c_p$ is easy to heat up to a high temperature, so a pulse of heat will spread faster.